# Extract date from the following string format

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

I cannot seem to get the date from this format in excel:

```
 Mon Jun 06 09:33:41 2016
```

I've tried date() and datevalue() and neither seem to work.

I do not need the time stamp, just month, day and year. I've also tried removing the time and name of day (ie. Mon) and converting Jun 06 2016. This is also not working for me.

Answer (score 4):

Use [MID function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MID-function-230833B1-28E7-4EF8-9286-EBA06A3C29AD) and [REPLACE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Replace-Function-6ACF209B-01B7-4078-B4B8-E0A4EF67D181) to parse the text then the [DATEVALUE function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/DATEVALUE-function-DF8B07D4-7761-4A93-BC33-B7471BBFF252) to covert the text-that-looks-like-a-date.

```
=DATEVALUE(REPLACE(MID(A1,5,99),7,9,","))
```

The result will be numeric (e.g. 42,527). Format the cell as a date.

Comment: this suffices for me ... `=DATEVALUE(MID(L20,5,250))`. Why wrap the `Replace`?

Comment: Typically, I've found that dates like a comma between day and year but you are correct that leaving the time in seems to overcome this. As long as we are playing 'formula golf' you should have left your answer available.

Comment: Is the hole par 3? For some reason, SO is not letting me undelete it ...

Comment: Try a page refresh; it should undelete it. I can only vote to undelete.  To my other point, manually stripping the time out of the string and `=DATEVALUE(REPLACE(MID(A6,5,99),7, 0,","))` is needed to put a comma in between the day and year.

Comment: got it on the replace. thanks. for some reason it's stuck. refreshed it a few times.

Comment: Write a new answer.

Comment: I guess that is because you are doing something contrary the author's wishes.

Comment: very weird behavoir - I can't even add another answer! nor undelete my original one. ... Am I on SO Watch! Hahahahaha

Comment: I've added a custom moderator flag; you may get pinged.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman "Have you tried turning it off and back on again?"

Comment: @ScottCraner - Believe it or not, I did. I logged out of SO and back-in. No dice.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Try again *with dice* 8)  hopefully the moderator flag works out.

Comment: @Jeeped if this is golf, I guess my typical answer/explination is somewhere near the max limit on strokes per hole!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `Mon` removing that we can get the correct format:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1, FIND(" ",A1),LEN(A1)))+ TIMEVALUE(MID(A1, FIND(" ",A1),LEN(A1)))
```

Then format it as you like.

[image]

If you only want the date:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1, FIND(" ",A1),LEN(A1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the complete column with the dates, goto **Data** then click **Text to Columns**. A window will pop up with Convert text to Columns Wizard as shown below.

[image]

2. Select Fixed width and click next, next and finish. You will get the values separated in columns. Now you have to concatenate values with DateValue to get the desired result.

[image]

3. Enter the formula =DATEVALUE(C1 & " " & B1 & " " & E1) as per different cell values with month, date and year value and change the format to date as it show the date value.

[image]

Comment: But you still end up with a string that excel can't do anything and not in any proper format.  change your formula in step 3 to `=DATEVALUE(C1 & " " & B1 & " " & E1)`  Then it will be a true date and not a string.